# How do I fix Golang package issues?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm starting a `Golang` course and I'm super new to developing, but having issues with packages. Currently on a lecture about Variables when I go to run the code it gives me

> package variables is not in std C:\Program Files\Go\src\variables

I think it might be an environment variables' issue as these keep coming up but I'm very unsure, I've tried looking at the paths in my environment variables and I don't seem to be finding the issue. Could anyone take a look at my screenshots and assist me with the issue? Thank you

[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305Zy.png)
[code im running in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JavHW.png)

I've ensured that the `mod` file is within the lectures project, I've checked my system environment variables. When running code in `git` I've made sure I'm in the working directory as to where the variable lecture is

Comment: Do `go run ./variables` (from the parent of the ./variables directory), or just do `go run .` (but from _inside_ the ./variables directory).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the application file to `main.go`

If that fixes it, then the problem is that you need initialize a module named "variables".

In the terminal run

```
$ go mod init your/path/to/vanillia
```

Then change the app file name back to *variables.go*

Until you get to more complicated apps you don't necessarily need to init a modules for your code. But then the app file must be *main.go*

Read more about code organization [here](https://go.dev/doc/code).

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command

```
go run main.go
```

since in go that's the only entrypoint to your application. the package should be named main as you did there as well.